# Woocommerce how to disable add to cart option

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, variable-product

Disable add to cart option When I purchased product.

I'm using "Martfury - WooCommerce Marketplace WordPress Theme".

This problem is only for variable product. simple product is fine.

Please check this link below and find attachment. please help anyone..

https://daisysell.com/product/2021-new-fashion-lady-oversize-rimless-square-bee-sunglasses/

Answer (score 0):

These hook will help you out

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

add this in functions.php

for more details refer
https://quadlayers.com/remove-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce/